# Kubuntu session switching shut down window manager

Tags: kubuntu

I'm new to Kubuntu. I created a new user account and wanted to start a new session for that user. Under switch session I selected "unused" and somehow ended up with the window manager completely shut down and at a login prompt (black screen, white text, no graphics). I've gone down this road before by mistake.  Why did this happen, and is there a way to get back without rebooting and losing everyone's sessions?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> got me back to normal, though I'm not quite sure what the purpose of "unused" is as a session option.